# Match function for more than one criteria

Tags: excel-formula

[image]

I want to get the row number of the row having 2 as ID and A in second column.

Comment: `=MATCH(2&"A",A2:A6&B2:B6,0)`

Comment: In this case, the concatenation approach already provided should work fine.  If you need a more generalized solution, the other common approach is to use `MATCH(SUMPRODUCT())`.  In this case, `=MATCH(1,SUMPRODUCT((A2:A6=2)*(B2:B6="A")),0)`.  I personally tend to default to this approach because it lets me apply both `AND` and `OR` criteria to a match, where the concatenation is only for `AND` criteria.

Comment: Its not working its giving me answer 1. =MATCH(1,SUMPRODUCT((DATA_AFTER20JAN!B:B=D2)*(DATA_AFTER20JAN!M:M=F2)),0).

Comment: i am using google sheet